# xPath - selects all before div with specific id

Tags: xpath

how to get elements before a specific id

```
<div id="content">
    <p> a
    <p> b 
    <p> c 
    <h2> d
    <h3> e
    <ul>
        <li> f
    <div id="before_here">
    <div id="some_other_divs">      
</div>
```

i wanna get all p tags, h2 tags or ul, li tags texts..

i've seen some answers but they give answers with range like preceding and following..

here's my code:

```
//div[@class="content"]/div[contains(@id,"before_here")]/*[preceding-sibling::div]/text()
```

i want my output to be a b c d e f

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`preceding-sibling`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XPath/Axes/preceding-sibling) fits the use case:

```
//div[@id="content"]/div[@id = "before_here"]/preceding-sibling::*/text()
```

Comment: div[@class="content"] i dont need to put this?

Comment: @Michimcchicken you can, but note that the `content` is an `id`, not `class`.

Comment: oh yes.. haha.. btw i want a b c d e f .. i dont want all the tags D: add text() ?

Comment: @Michimcchicken yup, check it out. Thanks.

Comment: omigsoh it worked! thanks! i'll accept your answer once stack allows -_- haha it says after 4 minutes -_- thankss!

Comment: btw i just checked.. how to get inside <p> tag? like <p> inside there's <strong> blabla </strong> </p>

Comment: @Michimcchicken preceding-sibling would only match the "direct" preceding siblings of an element. If you want to, say, get all the text nodes of every preceding sibling, you can do `//div[@id="content"]/div[@id = "before_here"]/preceding-sibling::*//text()` - note the double slash before the `text()`.